# Cannot instantiate custom class in android Activity layout XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, github

So my XML looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Calendar" >

<com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
    swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
    swipe:swipeAnimationTime="10"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="right"
    swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="80dip"
    swipe:swipeOffsetRight="80dip"
    swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I go into Graphical View in Eclipse, I get this error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

In Eclipse, in my Package Explorer window I have 3 packages.

- android-swipelistview-master
- myApp
- library (a dependency of android-swipelistview-master)

It looks like this: [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwJRX.png)

The strange thing is, I do not have any errors in either the android-swipelist-view-master nor the library packages. The only Warning is for an unused variable, which I'm hesitant to delete in case it is used elsewhere.  I simply am not instantiating it correctly, I suppose?  I don't know.  I can't figure this one out!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hLU9.png) is the myApp Package Properties > Android settings.

Comment: Did you add the library to the build path?

Comment: Both android-swipelistview-master and library are in the build path. Both of the Native Library Locations are pointing to the workspace items, android-swipelistview-master and library.

Comment: hey, did the problem get solved? I somehow got it to instatiate, but its throwing a null pointer at frontView and if i change my custom row, it is not getting reflected during run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After referencing all the libraries properly, I changed the XML to reference the SwipeListView like this:

```
<main.java.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
    swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
    swipe:swipeAnimationTime="10"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="right"
    swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="80dip"
    swipe:swipeOffsetRight="80dip"
    swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have those three packages, within your own project?

If you copied the source code into the android-swipelistview-master package, then you have changed the package name that swipelistview will be found in.

Try to figure out which package it is located in, within the new structure that you've created. I'm not positive from your description here, but try something like:

```
<android-swipelistview-master.com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:listSelector="#00000000"
swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
swipe:swipeAnimationTime="10"
swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
swipe:swipeMode="right"
swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="80dip"
swipe:swipeOffsetRight="80dip"
swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false" />
```

That is if you really meant that "android-swipelistview-master" is its own package.

You could achieve the desired result in a much cleaner way if you instead checked out the entire project directory from Github for this library, imported it into Eclipse, and referenced it as a library project. For more reading, check out: [the Android documentation on library projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).

Comment: I added a screenshot of my package explorer. I'm new to Eclipse, could you tell me if I've added android-swipelistview-master as its own package?

Comment: Okay, what your screenshot shows is that you did not copy the code to it's own package within your project, you have it in a separate project. That is good, you are following the library structure that I was suggesting at the end of my answer. You should right click on your project and add the android-swipelistview-master project as a library. Additionally, you need to right click on android-swipelistview-master and add "library" as a library project to it.

Comment: Should the Build Target for library and android-swipelistview-master both be Android 4.2.2 like the myApp is?

Comment: I think the build target of both library and android-swipelistview-master can be different. They could be set to whatever the developer had them originally set at.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your swipe project looks like this (I had to move the code from src/main/java to src):
[image]

Then define the project as library project, add NineOldAndroids as library (git://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids.git) and also the Android support library

[image]

After that you can add the android-swipelistview project to your main project and that should work (it does for me).

Comment: I've done all those things, and that doesn't work for some reason.  Should I rename library to be NineOldAndroids?

Comment: The list code is still in main/java so I wonder why it would compile at all...
Can you post your project properties/Android as well?

Comment: Posted.  This is a screenshot of the myApp's properties/Android window.

Comment: Again why's the list code in src/main/java/...? Can you move it so it's in the folder src/com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistviews (instead of src/main/java/com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview)

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem on JellyBean and Eclipse Juno.Views were showing correctly in emulator/device though, so it's something specific to the graphical layout editor.

Make sure the java file locations are correct.Also,try changing this line :

```
xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/Location"
```

where location is complete location (including package) of your custom widget's .java file. Also,if you declare the namespace in the beginning (with android and tool namespaces), you won't have to repeat it for every time the custom widget is used.